# Where to get connecting flight boarding pass?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, check-in, connecting-flights, delta-air-lines

I'm a young girl traveling for the first time alone in January. The trip will be from Connecticut to Jacksonville with a short layover in Atlanta. I'm only going to be traveling with a carry-on and a purse. The whole trip is going to be with Delta. I was told that since I'm only bringing a carry-on and a purse I can just check in online 24 hours before my flight, then when I go to the airport I can print my boarding pass and not have to go to the check-in counter, just go to Security after printing my boarding pass then just find my gate.

Is this true?

I know that at the airport in Connecticut I'm printing my boarding pass to get on the plane that's stopping in Atlanta but where to I get my boarding pass that takes me from Atlanta to Jacksonville?

I've called Delta several times and asked them and each person I talked to keeps telling me different things:

- One person told me at the airport in Connecticut I'll get both
  boarding passes.
- Then another person told me I use the same boarding pass that I used
  to get to Atlanta to get to Jacksonville.
- Then someone else told me I only get one boarding pass in Connecticut
  and that only gets me to Atlanta then in Atlanta I get my next
  boarding pass to get on the plane to Jacksonville at the gate in
  Atlanta. I'm so stressed out, confused, and nervous none of this
  makes sense.

What do I do once I get to Atlanta?

What boarding pass do I use to get to my final destination and where do I get it?

Comment: Connecticut is a *state*. Did you mean the Hartford Bradley International Airport (BDL)?

Comment: If you are a child you may be able to book special assistance at the airport.

Comment: @chx Maybe it's just me but your comment looks super-snarky. I'm pretty sure the asker is aware that Connecticut is a state. If you need to know which airport they'll be flying from (do you expect it will make a difference to the checkin procedure?), you could ask that in a friendly way, rather than lecturing, especially given that you're talking to a minor. And the asker _is_ travelling from Connecticut. They could be more precise but they're not wrong.

Comment: I've flown Delta many, many times. When you check in online 24 hours in advance (and you can, regardless of luggage), you should get all required boarding passes. They'll show your departure gates, including the one in ATL, but make sure you're at the right one once there, as they do get changed.

Comment: @Dorothy Agreed that you'll get all the boarding passes for the journey but I usually find that they often give no gate information at all and, otherwise, usually just the first flight. (Delta but usually one leg international and one leg intra-US.) But, since you need to check the monitors anyway, it doesn't much matter if the gate's on the boarding pass or not.

Answer (score 6):

There are two options which you can select

Number One

On the day of your flight, arrive at the airport 3 hours before the flight. Proceed to the check-in counter and present your ticket + passport/ID. They will give you 2 boarding passes; one for CT to ATL and one for ATL to JAX. Verify your name on the boarding pass and wait for the flight.

Number Two

You can [online check in](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/check-in/options.html) X number of hours before the flight. X is different for different airlines but in most cases it is 24 hours. While checking in you may have the luxury of selecting a preferred seat on the plane. Note that if your connecting flight is operated by the same airline and it's in the same itinerary (has the same airline reservation code which is needed to online check in; it is written on the itinerary) you will be able to check in to both flights and can print boarding passes for both as well. Online checking in is a simple process with a little added benefits i.e. seat selection, e-boarding pass, meal selection, arrive at the airport 2 hours earlier, avoid the check-in etc all based on the airline terms and conditions.

Comment: Seriously? Y' all upvoted an unsourced answer??

Comment: Still wrong source, the OP is looking for http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/support/faqs/during-your-trip/checking-in-faqs.html as I added in my answer...

Comment: There's no need to check in three hours before a domestic flight in the US, especially at a relatively small airport. Two hours is plenty and one hour is almost certainly enough.

Comment: Three hours!? And "two hours earlier" with a pre-printed boarding card? You must really love airport shops ;)

Comment: Small airports are small. And fast. Here, I leave the house a bit more than an hour before departure.

Comment: lol i have mostly visited airports like doha, dubai, jfk hence the 2 & 3 hours :p

Answer (score 5):

While you could print your boarding pass there's no reason to, a mobile boarding pass will do. I will presume by CT you meant CLT, Charlotte that is. You can see in the [eboarding pass FAQ](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/support/faqs/during-your-trip/eboarding-pass-faqs.html) that Charlotte and Atlanta both supports the mobile boarding pass. You can use the Delta app or just receive it in email. All you need for boarding is a barcode, after all.

You will get all the boarding passes when you check in, online or otherwise, it's one check in for both flights, you can do that any time starting 24 hours prior. As the [Checking In FAQs](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/support/faqs/during-your-trip/checking-in-faqs.html) says:

> What If I Have Connecting Flights?
>
> No problem. You will receive a separate boarding document for each of your flights when you check in.

Don't forget to charge your phone and have fun on your trip! Do not be so anxious, it is a very simple thing to fly these days.

Comment: No by ct I meant Connecticut... I would do e boarding passss if I could but I can't because the ct airport doesn't support them..

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that. It's clearly spelled out in the Checking in FAQ.

Comment: There's no such thing as "CT airport". You most likely mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley_International_Airport and yes it is supported. I do not even think there's any airport in the USA left which doesn't support a mobile boarding pass.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a bit of a broad view of how everything is going to work the day you fly.

First off, when your flight was booked, if you have the receipt, there should be a six-character code on there, probably listed as a flight confirmation #. 24 hours before the flight, you can go to Delta.com and Check In using that code. If you check in online, you can print your boarding passes for both flights while you're at home. Depending on the ticket purchased and how full your flight is, you may also be able to change your seat while doing this, if you'd prefer a different one. Also, if you do this, since you aren't checking any luggage in, you can skip checking in at the airport, and go straight to security.

Sidenote: if you have a smartphone, Delta has an app for iOS and Android that you can also check in through as well. It will give you a digital boarding pass as well. (again, for both flights)

When you arrive at the airport, (probably 2 hrs ahead of time, but that's up to you - you want to 100% be at the gate 30+ minutes before scheduled departure) if you didn't get your boarding pass online, you should stop by the Delta check-in area, which will be near where you walk in. They will have kiosks where you can check-in, again using that 6-character code. If you don't have that code, or you just want to ask any questions, don't hesitate to just ask for help or go to the check-in desk. When you're done here, you'll have your boarding passes and can go through security.

I'd recommend looking quick at the airport maps of the airports that you're flying through as well, just so you have a rough idea of what to expect. If you're flying out of Bradley, I wouldn't worry much there, but Atlanta is a large & busy airport, but it's laid out in a way that's easy to know where you are at any given time. So I'd recommend looking at their terminal map, at least, to get a feel for how to get around. (you won't know the gates you will fly out of until a couple hours before each flight)

If you have any questions while you're flying, don't be afraid to ask someone at Delta. You'll have people at the check-in desk, gate agents at the gates, and since you're flying through Atlanta -- Delta's largest hub -- there will be plenty of staff around the airport that can help.

Answer (score 3):

Every place Delta services has a self check-in terminal. You can go there, check-in, and print boarding passes. When I did that the last time I got all the boarding passes for that day. So when you print them, you should get both the boarding pass for ATL and the boarding pass for JAX. If it doesn't, ask a counter agent. Also, you're flying the main airline all the way and not a connection. The chances there will be an issue for you are very low.

As mentioned in the other answers, I would skip the kiosk altogether and use the Delta app instead. You will get both boarding passes on the app. You can also check-in via the app. But the other answers don't mention something the app does that's VERY handy (especially in ATL): flight data. The app will tell you what gate your connecting flight is at. ATL has 6 separate concourses and there's a very good chance you'll arrive at one and depart from another. You'll also get notices about gate changes, flight delays and when boarding starts (in some cases before the gate agent even knows). Best of all, you can rebook from the app, should things go awry.